# What does an overflow means exactly?

Tags: math, assembly, integer, overflow, twos-complement

I have read two definitions for what an overflow means.

Say that we have the following addition:

```
 11111111
 00000001
 --------
100000000
```

The first definition I have read is that the fact that the result did not fit into 8 bits (it needed 9 bits in this example), then this is called an overflow.

---

The other definition I have read is that if we have an addition for two signed integers (two's complement integers for example):

```
 10011001
 10111011
 --------
101010100
```

Then if the 8 bits result (`01010100`) have a sign that is different from the sign for the two integers (and it is different in this example), then this is called an overflow.

Which definition is correct?

Comment: The first definition is base. The second is after-effect

Comment: They are effectively the same thing

Comment: One is signed and the other is unsigned overflow and you should think of them that way.  In both overflow cases it simply means you do not have enough bits to properly represent the result.  Basically you need one more bit.

Answer (score 6):

Both cases would have been solved by adding one more bit to result.
As the [Wikipedia page for Integer Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) states, integer overflow occurs, when the result of operation does not fit the target register/variable. E.g. 0x10000 * 0x10000 is also an overflow for 32-bit integers.

Typical processor architectures separate the cases of unsigned integer overflow vs signed integer overflow to two distinct flags in status register; Carry/Borrow for unsigned and Overflow for signed addition.

Answer (score 5):

They are both correct. An overflow happens when the calculation on the number has resulted in an error due to the result no longer fitting in with the stored format of the number.

So in the first case, the overflow happens because you need 9 bits and only 8 are available (meaning the number now stored in the byte does not accurately reflect the answer).

In the second case, the overflow happens because the result interferes with the signed bit also resulting in the byte containing an incorrect value.

Comment: 'Resulted in an error' is going to be misleading from some readers as transitions in CF OF & AF flags merely indicates the result of a previous operation. Errors in X86, assuming that's the architecture we're talking about, will throw an exception.

Comment: I meant in the sense of a mathematical error rather than a runtime error. In the Z80, both cases triggered flags in the CPU which could be tested to see whether an overflow had occurred.